# Is there a way to give a popup when you click search on a search engine?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup, search-engine

I am trying to write a prank program to run on chrome so that when my mom hits search on a search engine, it give a popup saying "Did you really need to look that up?". However, I am a bit of a noob and need some general direction and/or help on this one. I would like to write this in python as it is the language I know best, but if I would have to use another language, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome extention, tampermonkey, that allows you to run custom javascript scripts when the page is loaded. You can use that to make a function that shows an alert when search is pressed.

Install the extension, open it, create a new userscript, remove whats inside and paste this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         alert on google search
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  show an alert on google search
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.google.*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    var searchButton = 
document.querySelectorAll("button[type=submit]");
    searchButton.onclick = function(){
        alert("Are you sure?");
    }
})();
```

The first 9 lines tells tampermonkey the name of the script and other things that aren't important now.

`var searchButton = document.querySelectorAll("button[type=submit]");` creates a variable calles searchButton and puts the search button in it. The last 3 lines tells the browser that when the button is pressed, an alert should pop up.